# Need some help on a Regex match / replace pattern

Tags: c#, regex

My ultimate goal here is to turn the following string into JSON, but I would settle for something that gets me one step closer by combining the fieldname with each of the values.

Sample Data:

```
Field1:abc;def;Field2:asd;fgh;
```

Using Regex.Replace(), I need it to at least look like this:

```
Field1:abc,Field1:def,Field2:asd,Field2:fgh
```

Ultimately, this result would be awesome if it can be done via Regex in a single call.

```
{"Field1":"abc","Field2":"asd"},{"Field1":"def","Field2":"fgh"}
```

I've tried many different variations of this pattern, but can't seem to get it right:

```
(?:(\w+):)*?(?:([^:;]+);)
```

Only one other example I could find that is doing something similar, but just enough differences that I can't quite put my finger on it.

[Regex to repeat a capture across a CDL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914587/regex-to-repeat-a-capture-across-a-cdl)

```
EDIT:
```

Here's my solution.  I'm not going to post it as a "Solution" because I want to give credit to one that was posted by others.  In the end, I took a piece from each of the posted solutions and came up with this one.  Thanks to everyone who posted.  I gave credit to the solution that compiled, executed fastest and had the most accurate results.

```
    string hbi = "Field1:aaa;bbb;ccc;ddd;Field2:111;222;333;444;";

    Regex re = new Regex(@"(\w+):(?:([^:;]+);)+");
    MatchCollection matches = re.Matches(hbi);

    SortedDictionary<string, string> dict = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();

    for (int x = 0; x < matches.Count; x++)
    {
        Match match = matches[x];
        string property = match.Groups[1].Value;

        for (int i = 0; i < match.Groups[2].Captures.Count; i++)
        {
            string key = i.ToString() + x.ToString();
            dict.Add(key, string.Format("\"{0}\":\"{1}\"", property, match.Groups[2].Captures[i].Value));
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", dict.Values));
```

Comment: If the performance of LINQ is close to Regex, I'm game.

Comment: It would be Interesting to compare on large input string

Comment: I agree.  The same data shown here is quite small compared to what I'm attempting to convert. The real object contains 31 fields and could contain 100-200 objects.

Comment: @Chris_Gessler, is there a predictable way to recognize the field names? I'm guessing it's not literally Field1,Field2.  The delimiter ';' is used to delimit values in a tuple as well as the tuples, which makes it tricky.  Or is it always garunteed to be field name, two values, then field delimiter?

Comment: Fields are always followed by a colon.  Values are always followed by a semicolon

Comment: @Chris Gessler: who generates such a format string? `Field1:abc;def;Field2:asd;fgh; `

Comment: @sll, It's a propritary format. It doesn't really use colon or semicolon, it uses 0x0002 (begin text) and 0x0003 (end text), but colon and semicolon is easier to type :)

Comment: @ValAkkapeddi, The format is actually field1[0x0002]value1[0x0003]value2[0x0003]...valueN[0x0003]field2[0x0002]value1[0x0003] etc... I CAN tell you that the number of values for each field are the same for all fields. So, if field1 has 3 values, fieldN will have three values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an idea that it should be possible to do this in a shorter and more clear way. It ended up not being all that much shorter and you can question if it's more clear. At least it's another way to solve the problem.

```
var str = "Field1:abc;def;Field2:asd;fgh";
var rows = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
int index = 0;
string value;
string fieldname = "";

foreach (var s in str.Split(';'))
{
    if (s.Contains(":"))
    {
        index = 0;
        var tmp = s.Split(':');
        fieldname = tmp[0];
        value = tmp[1];
    }
    else
    {
        value = s;
        index++;
    }

    if (rows.Count < (index + 1))
        rows.Insert(index, new Dictionary<string, string>());

    rows[index][fieldname] = value;
}

var arr = rows.Select(dict => 
                   String.Join("," , dict.Select(kv => 
                       String.Format("\"{0}\":\"{1}\"", kv.Key, kv.Value))))
                   .Select(r => "{" + r + "}");
var json = String.Join(",", arr );
Debug.WriteLine(json);
```

Outputs:

```
{"Field1":"abc","Field2":"asd"},{"Field1":"def","Field2":"fgh"}
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. Your solution compiled, was fastest (among other compilable solutions) and provided the most accurate results.

Answer (score 2):

[Now you have two problems](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html)

I don't think regular expressions will be the best way to handle this. You should probably start by splitting on semicolons, then loop through the results looking for a value that starts with "Field1:" or "Field2:" and collect the results into a Dictionary.

Treat this as pseudo code because I have not compiled or tested it:

```
string[] data = input.Split(';');
dictionary<string, string> map = new dictionary<string, string>();

string currentKey = null;
foreach (string value in data)
{
    // This part should change depending on how the fields are defined.
    // If it's a fixed set you could have an array of fields to search,
    // or you might need to use a regular expression.
    if (value.IndexOf("Field1:") == 0 || value.IndexOf("Field2:"))
    {
        string currentKey = value.Substring(0, value.IndexOf(":"));
        value = value.Substring(currentKey.Length+1);
    }
    map[currentKey] = value;
}
// convert map to json
```

Comment: Yup... the 'ole brute force way.  Loops.  With C# 4.0, Linq, Dynamics, Generics, etc... there must be a way to deserialize this predictable format into JSON without loops.

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to avoid loops, but why make it more complicated? Even if you don't see the loop, it's still there with Linq, etc.

Comment: My point is that C# has come a long long way since 1.0.  I believe there's a Regex pattern that will work, so I'd rather go with that solution and deserialze the JSON string to my objects. If I'm going to loop through the string, I can build the objects on my own without deserializing.

Comment: FYI: splitting on semi-colons would add the next record set's fieldname to the end of the first record. This is why I didn't use the split function to begin with.  Maybe a regex split would work, but then we're back to regex again. LOL

Answer (score 1):

I would go with RegEx as the simplest and most straightforward way to *parse* the strings, but I'm sorry, pal, I couldn't come up with a clever-enough replacement string to do this in one shot.

I hacked it out for fun through, and the  monstrosity below accomplishes what you need, albeit hideously. :-/

```cs
        Regex r = new Regex(@"(?<FieldName>\w+:)*(?:(?<Value>(?:[^:;]+);)+)");

        var matches = r.Matches("Field1:abc;def;Field2:asd;fgh;moo;"); // Modified to test "uneven" data as well.

        var tuples = new[] { new { FieldName = "", Value = "", Index = 0 } }.ToList(); tuples.Clear();

        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            var matchGroups = match.Groups;
            var fieldName = matchGroups[1].Captures[0].Value;
            int index = 0;
            foreach (Capture cap in matchGroups[2].Captures)
            {
                var tuple = new { FieldName = fieldName, Value = cap.Value, Index = index };
                tuples.Add(tuple);
                index++;
            }

        }

        var maxIndex = tuples.Max(tup => tup.Index);

        var jsonItemList = new List<string>();

        for (int a = 0; a < maxIndex+1; a++)
        {
            var jsonBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            jsonBuilder.Append("{");

            foreach (var tuple in tuples.Where(tup => tup.Index == a))
            {
                jsonBuilder.Append(string.Format("\"{0}\":\"{1}\",", tuple.FieldName, tuple.Value));
            }
            jsonBuilder.Remove(jsonBuilder.Length - 1, 1); // trim last comma.
            jsonBuilder.Append("}");
            jsonItemList.Add(jsonBuilder.ToString());
        }

        foreach (var item in jsonItemList)
        {
            // Write your items to your document stream.
        }
```

Comment: Nice use of Tuples, combined with Linq and Lambda.  I may have to go with this except there's a question very similar to mine that does what I want.  Just don't need the <CRLF> stuff and don't have anything to Split() upon. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914587/regex-to-repeat-a-capture-across-a-cdl